# How can I extract sentences from the string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, match

How can I extract sentences from the string through the match() method?

**Example:** "Wait... Whats happen? ... Whats wrong with you..? -Nothing. Seems i've speeking..! -Really??? -You bet!"

**Returns:**

`["Wait...", "Whats happen?", "Whats wrong with you..?", "-Nothing.", "Seems i've speeking..!", "Realy???", "You bet!"]`

Comment: So, a "sentence" is a character sequence either ending with `.`, `?` or `!`? What about `"E.g. this sentence?"` What have you tried so far?

Comment: You can do it however you want.

Comment: It could ending by `.`, `...`, `..!`, `..?`, `???`, `!!!`, `??`, `!!`, `!`, `?`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str.match(/(.*?(?:\.|\?|!))(?: |$)/g)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/akXF3/

Comment: Change `(?:\.|\?|!)` to `[.?!]` (if it is going to be a single character)